# Why are some branches of mathematics called 'theory' and others not?

Tags: terminology, definition, math-history

We say: graph **theory** , group **theory**, number **theory** , set **theory**, what is definition of **theory**?

We also say abstract algebra, real analysis, but why we do not say abstract algebra **theory** or real analysis **theory**? What is meaning of **theory**?

Comment: I would have thought that in "theory of everything", "everything" is at least as much in need of definition as "theory" :-)

Comment: @joriki: The prodigal son returns!

Comment: @AsafKaragila: :-)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory

Comment: Why the down vote? It is a good question. +1

Comment: IMHO this is a question about language rather than math. In the listed examples the word *theory* is paired with an object. The roots of the words *algebra* and *analysis*  describe (IIRC) something like a methodology, and work well as stand alone words. This is a bit fuzzy. I lack the proper linguistic terms to phrase this well, sorry.

Answer (score 10):

The names you listed in the first paragraph are built from an *object* of investigation. You study objects named X and prove a bunch of things about them, so you call it X theory.

So, it's "group theory" because it concerns the properties of groups.

We would not say "real analysis theory" because "real analysis" is not a name of the object under investigation. We are not proving theorems about some properties of real analysis. But it could be called "real function theory", which is indeed a term in use, albeit not as common as "real analysis".

"Complex analysis" vs "Complex function theory" is close enough so that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_analysis) acknowledges both.

Whether one or the other name becomes more widespread is influenced by many things, including the personal preferences of people who were particularly influential when the theory was in formative stages.